# SystemC Port Conversion

Tags: c++, ports, systemc

I am trying to convert one type of SystemC port into another:

from:

```
sc_port<sc_fifo_out_if<Type> >
```

to:

```
sc_export<tlm::tlm_analysis_if<Type> >
```

I used this class with a thread to convert between the types.

```
class port_converter : public sc_core::sc_module{
public:
    sc_port<sc_fifo_in_if<Type> > in_converter;
    sc_port<tlm::tlm_analysis_if<Type> > out_converter;

    // c'tor
    SC_HAS_PROCESS(port_converter);
    port_converter(sc_module_name nm) :
        sc_module(nm), in_converter("in"), out_converter("out") {
        SC_THREAD(main_action);
    }

    // main action 
    void main_action() {
        while (1){
            out_converter->write(in_converter->read());
        }
    }
};
```

[The solution diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDPpG.png)

Is there a simpler way to convert between these types of ports?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces `sc_fifo_out_if` and `tlm_analysis_if` are not fully compatible. So here is probably the best you can get. Simulation will stop with an error if someone will try to use incompatible method.

Update: I'm not sure if `tlm_analysis_if` guarantees non-blocking operation.

```
template <typename T>
struct my_converter : sc_fifo_out_if<T>, sc_core::sc_module {

    sc_export<sc_fifo_out_if<T>>          in{"in"};
    sc_port<tlm::tlm_analysis_if<T>>      out{"out"};

    my_converter(sc_core::sc_module_name){
        in.bind(*this);
    }

    bool nb_write(const T &t) override {
        out->write(t);
    }

    const sc_event &data_read_event() const override {
        SC_REPORT_ERROR("my_converter", "data_read_event not supported!!");
        return m_data_read_event;
    }

    void write(const T &t) override {
        nb_write(t);
    }

    int num_free() const override {
        SC_REPORT_ERROR("my_converter", "num_free not supported!!");
        return 1;
    }

private:
    sc_event m_data_read_event; // this even will never happen;
};
```